# Difference between initialization and zeroing, and new() and make() in GoLang

Tags: go

I am coming from C# background, and I am little confused with the way of GoLang initialization and zeroing definitions. I think you can guess that this confusion arises from `make()` and `new()` functions in Go. What should I expect happening internally when these methods run? What happens when initialization and zeroing happens?

I know that there is an `init()` function in GoLang that is used to initialize packages. But I think it is different than this.

Anyways, what is the difference between them?

## Update

I answered my own question, please check it to see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I have figured it and decided to share what I figured so far.

### `make()` vs. `new()`

I think I now understand the difference between `make()` and `new()`. At first, it was little confusing, but here what I got:

`new` is simply like `new` in C# or Java, but since there is no constructor in Go, all the fields (like in Java and C# terminology) will be zeroed. Zeroing means more like defaulting the fields. So if the field type is `int`, then it will be `0`, or if it is a `struct`, then it will be defaulted to `nil`, and `""` for `string` types. It is actually similar to C# and Java when there is only parameterless constructor available and you are not setting the members to something else manually.

However, types like `map`, `slice`, and `channel`s are different. They are different because they are actually wrapper types that wrap an array type to hold the values behind the scenes. So something like `List<T>` or `ArrayList` in C# and Java. But using `new` is not enough in this situation, because the underlying array should be initialized to an empty array to be usable. Because you cannot add or remove from a field of type array which is `nil` (or `null`). Therefore, they provided a `make()` method to help you to initialize `slices` and such.

So what happens when you use `new()` over slices, for instance? Simple: Since the underlying array will be `nil`, the slice will be pointing at a `nil` array.

So `new()` would look like the following C#/Java code:

```
public class Person{
   public string Name;
   public int Age;
   public Address HomeAddress;
}

var person = new Person();
Console.WriteLine(person.Name); // ""
Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // 0
Console.WriteLine(person.HomeAddress); // null
```

`make()`, on the other hand, would look like this for `slice`,`map`, and `channel`s:

```
public class PersonList{
   // We are initializing the array so that we can use it.
   // Its capacity can increase.
   private Person[] _personList = new Person[100];
   public void Add(Person p){}
   public void Remove(Person p){}
   public Person Get(int index){}
}
```

### Initialization vs. Zeroing

Simply speaking, zeroing is a form of initialization. At first, I thought they were different but they are not. Initialization is a more general term, whereas if you are set the fields (properties, etc.) of a struct or a variable to its type default such as `0`, `nil`, `""`, `false`, etc., then this is called zeroing. However, you can, for instance, use [Composite Literals](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) like `hello := Hello{name="world"}`, which is similar to `var hello = new Hello() {Name = "World"}` in C#, then you initialize your `Hello` object with a `name` field set to `world`.

In C#, at the time you say `new List<string>()`, [the underlying array field is initialized to a new array], and `make)` is performing a similar operation behind the scenes but as a language construct (built in the language itself):

(http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646):

[image]

So `new` does zeroing and returns a pointer back. Whereas `make()` initializes to underlying array to an array with default values for each element and returns the value itself rather than a pointer.

Comment: new does NOT zero anything, it simply returns a pointer to the type, all types are zeroed by default: `var t Type` is zeroed, `t := &Type{}` or `var t Type; ptr := &t` is the same as `t := new(Type)`, but the type is zeroed before new returns the pointer.

Comment: @OneOfOne: After some time, your comment started making sense :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`new` returns a pointer to the type, and it's the only way to return a pointer to a native type in one step (aka int, float, complex):

```
intPtr := new(int)
// or
var i int
intPtr := &i
```

`make` is for initializing channels, slices and maps.

All variables are zeroed on creation, regardless of how you create them.

The spec about make: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels

The spec about zero value: https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value

Comment: But for some reason I feel like this answer is lacking. For instance, what happens when I use it on a struct? And not sure what it returning pointer using new has anything to do with my question? Sorry, perhaps I am not getting it yet.

Comment: @Tarik new returns a pointer, that is its function, it's the equivalent of `&type{}`. You can't use make on a struct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It led me to the one I figured finally.

Answer (score 1):

`new(T)` allocates zeroed storage for a new item of type T and returns its address, a value of type *T: it returns a pointer to a newly allocated zero value of type T, ready for use; it applies to value types like arrays and structs. It is
equivalent to &T{ }

`make(T)` returns an initialized value of type T; it applies only to the 3 built-in
reference types: slices, maps, and channels.

```
var p *[]int = new([]int) // *p == nil; with len and cap 0
//or    
p := new([]int)

var v []int = make([]int, 10, 50)
//or
v := make([]int, 10, 50)

//This allocates an array of 50 ints and then creates a slice v with length 10 and capacity 50 pointing
//to the first 10 elements of the array
```